# Strange appearance of text/background in gedit

Tags: 17.04, gedit

When I open my text editor and try to write there this is happening.

[image: gedit open with transparent background, orange highlighting, strange fonts and text in black and white looking superimposed]

What should I do?

Comment: Try to rename `~/.config/gedit` after closing gedit, so open it again and see if it's gone. Is not your a keyboard issue?

Answer (score 3):

Just solved this issue after months of annoyance, by removing the line `run_im xim` from `~/.xinputrc` thanks to the people commenting on Ubuntu's issue tracker at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1620806

I have another line there for disabling the touch screen but that one is fine.

Now why would the setting of the input method handler affect the background redrawing, I can't even imagine.

Comment: Yey, it works for me! It's great that you come back to post a solution when you solve your only problem! You should also accept your own answer so it is visible to others that there is a good solution. See the [Help Center article](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) on the subject for more information.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included a line about what the `run_im xim` line does and why removing it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe that your config for `gedit` is messed up you can try to remove the config and reinstall

```
# Backup the config
tar cvzf ~/gedit-config.backup.tar.gz ~/.config/gedit/
# remove it
rm -rf ~/.config/gedit/
# reinstall gedit
sudo apt-get purge gedit -y && sudo apt-get install gedit -y
```

Comment: No.... not at all clear