# Display Problems Basic Apps

Tags: display, gdm, xserver

i am running an Ubuntu 18.04.1 with all Packages up to Date. At the moment i have trouble Displaying some Programms such as gdit and calc.

In Gedit the background should be white, but it is somehow transparent and i am not able to use the Programm.

[image: Gedit]

In Calculator seams to be a similiar problem somehow the inputfield is not rendered correctly.

[image: Calculator]

I tried to find some solutions but dont know in wich direction i should look.

I gdm3 is spamming these messages in syslog but i dont know if they correlate with the problem.

```
Oct 16 14:45:00  /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1217]: (WW) modeset(0): flip queue failed: Permission denied
Oct 16 14:45:00  /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1217]: (WW) modeset(0): Page flip failed: Permission denied
```

I also tried to change the driver for my graphic card but to problem was not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution [Strange appearance of text/background in gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964646/strange-appearance-of-text-background-in-gedit) from Alberto González Palomo

> Just solved this issue after months of annoyance, by removing the line run_im xim from ~/.xinputrc thanks to the people commenting on Ubuntu's issue tracker at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1620806
>
> I have another line there for disabling the touch screen but that one is fine.
>
> Now why would the setting of the input method handler affect the background redrawing, I can't even imagine.